# (ONIE) stg: command not found and Error 127 in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, makefile

I was trying to follow this guide: https://github.com/opencomputeproject/onie/blob/master/machine/kvm_x86_64/INSTALL but have gotten stuck.

On this line: `make MACHINE=kvm_x86_64 all`, I get `stg: command not found` when it is trying to apply a patch. I get Error 127 on a make command. Here's the output:

[image: Error]

I have g++ and git installed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `stg` appears to be from [stacked git](https://gna.org/projects/stgit). There is probably a package for it.

Comment: I've looked online for a while and have not found a package for it.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=stg

Comment: @EtanReisner Thank you very much! However, I have run into another problem you may know how to fix. The error is `expat is missing or unusable`. I installed expat but am still getting the error. Pic: http://i.imgur.com/tCNLSAN.png

Comment: You probably just need the dev/devel expat package.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, that was it. Now it says `python is missing or unusable`. I have python installed as well as the dev packages. I'm sorry if I am annoying you.

Comment: Without seeing more I'm not sure what that might mean other than perhaps a python version mismatch. And no, you aren't annoying me but this has gone beyond a reasonable usage of this site at this point. Did you look at https://github.com/opencomputeproject/onie/wiki/Building-ONIE ? You should probably use their mailing list (or other communication channel) at this point and, assuming that link doesn't fix the problem, point out to them that they are apparently missing a good bit of documentation on their build requirements.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thank you for all your help! I did figure it out though. I think my python-dev was corrupted in someway because I reinstalled it and the process completed. I'll make an answer below so no one has to find all the packages needed to build this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built this on Ubuntu Desktop 15.04. For anyone else trying to build ONIE virtual machine, install these packages first:

**Packages**

- [qemu-kvm](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qemu-kvm)
- [git](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=git)
- [stg](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=stg)
- [gperf](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gperf)
- [bison](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bison)
- [flex](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=flex)
- [autoconf](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=autoconf)
- [texinfo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=texinfo)
- [gawk](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gawk)
- [libtool](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libtool)
- [libtool-bin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libtool-bin)
- [libncurses5-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libncurses5-dev)
- [libexpat1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libexpat1)
- [libexpat1-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libexpat1-dev)
- [python2.7-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python2.7-dev)
- [python3.4-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3.4-dev)
- [xorriso](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xorriso)

You can install most of these with `sudo apt-get install <package>`. You should be able to follow the [ONIE guide](https://github.com/opencomputeproject/onie/blob/master/machine/kvm_x86_64/INSTALL) now and set it up. Thanks to EtanReisner for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

From the ONIE project wiki [Building ONIE](https://github.com/opencomputeproject/onie/wiki/Building-ONIE):

> For a Debian-based system, a Makefile target exists that installs the required packages on your build machine. The ONIE project will maintain this target for the current stable version of Debian. This target requires the use of sudo(8), since package installation requires root privileges:

```
$ cd build-config
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ make debian-prepare-build-host
```

Comment: Using Debian Stretch, the `make debian-prepare-build-host` failed with error 127. I had to `apt-get install sudo` as root first and then this worked.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu,  install stg package by,

```
sudo apt-get install stgit
```

the error stg: command not found should be resolved.