# Build ONIE, fatal: ambiguous argument 'head' unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: git

I try to build the ONIE install images. I cd to path/onie-master/build-config.

At first, after I typed make, it showed:

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

I `git init` under path/onie-master/build-config. It still happened.

So I `git init` under path/onie-master this time, It shows:

`fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`

What's the problem?

Comment: I don't think the solution is to just execute `git init` all over the place in the hopes this fixes it. If `make` expects a git repository then there probably should've been a git repository present to begin with. How did you obtain the code?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I obtain the code from [here](https://github.com/opencomputeproject/onie)

Comment: So did you download an archive or did you clone the repository?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I just download the whole code as a zip. What archive should I download? I `git init` under my document folder and `git clone https://github.com/opencomputeproject/onie.git`. Is it right?

Answer (score -1):

You can clone the repository by `git clone`, no needs to `git init`

use this: `git clone https://github.com/opencomputeproject/onie.git`

And then follow the build instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36048254/1912367)